# Как получить высоту текста в пикселях, при заданной ширине

Tags: java, android

Добрый вечер, подскажите, как можно получить высоту текста в пикселях, задав нужную ширину.

Например:

У меня есть переменная STRING с содержимым: "У попа была собака он её любил она съела кусок мяса он её убил".

Мне нужно создать TextView с определенной шириной, например 800 в ширину, а высоту я не знаю, т.к. переменная String может быть и 1000 слов.

Мне нужно рассчитать высоту, что-бы создать TextView, и поместить в текст переменную.

В Objective-C я сделал это так:

```
UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width-70, MAXFLOAT);

CGSize labelSize = [STRING sizeWithFont:cellFont
                            constrainedToSize:constraintSize
                                lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

return labelSize.height + 37.0f;
```

Comment: Возможно вам надо лишь поставить высоту по содержимому, т.е. `wrap_content`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, это можно бы было. Но у меня ниже есть еще кнопки, которые я сдвигаю через topMargin, поэтому мне обязательно нужно знать высоту текста.

Comment: Вообще мы так на андроиде не делаем... Может вам просто не через маржин отступ делать, а поместить кноки и тестовое поле в LinearLayout вертикальный? Так они всегда будут точно снизу. Или в RelativeLayout и там назначить им быть ниже текста

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, сейчас я так и сделал. Но теперь мне нужно знать высоту RelativeLayout, потому что у меня помимо текста есть еще и изображение) Да и куча нюансов.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб смотрите, нашел вот такое: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829703/java-getting-a-font-with-a-specific-height-in-pixels  ответ пользователя WhiteFang34, но не пойму, что такое Font??

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а, стоп, у них кажется всё наоборот :D

Comment: Скорее всего вашу разметку можно реализовать без таких действий) А Font это, надо полагать некий объект, содержащий информацию о шрифте. Видимо, из него можно получить высоту букв/строк, а из TextView, после его отрисовки можно получить кол-во строк и отсюда высоту в пикселях. Но это неоптимальное решение.

Comment: В Android разметка верстается по другим принципам в силу большой фрагментации устройств и как вы там делали на iOS лучше сразу забыть. Никто не указывает и не считает высоту и ширину виджетов в абсолютных значениях, так как на одном устройстве "800 в ширину" будет больше экрана, а на другом меньше половины. Начать приобщаться можно с изучения официального руководства.